# How can we check whether one array contains one or more elements of another array in #?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a an array of strings:e.g:

```
string [] names ={"P","A","B","G","F","K","R"}
```

I have another array :

```
string [] subnames={"P","G","O"}
```

How can we check whether names array has any elements of subnames array.

In the above example "P" and "G" are there in names.

Comment: No..Just came across a scenario and I don't want to use if condition.so thought of looking for a faster and better approach

Comment: @palakmehta: `if condition` is _no_ approach. Also, what means _better_?

Comment: Better in terms of number of time complexity.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here is a Linq solution that should give you what you need:

```
names.Any(x => subnames.Contains(x))
```

Comment: This is what OP actually asked _"How can we check whether names array has any elements of subnames array"_

Comment: @TimSchmelter: You don't think this will produce that result? Or perhaps reversing it so that it says `subnames.Any(x => names.Contains(x))` will produce a different result?

Comment: It's worth noting that this solution scales much more poorly than those using the `intersect` methods.

Answer (score 19):

The absolute simplest way would be to use the [Enumerable.Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) method. Then us the [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697) method on the result

```
bool containsValues = names.Intersect(subnames).Any();
```

Comment: The result should be a `bool` _"How can we check whether names array has any elements of subnames array"_

Comment: @TimSchmelter Consider it an exercise of the reader to take a solution that's 90% of the way there and complete it.

Comment: What if , I want to return only a boolean value . i.e. if names array has any elements of subnames array then we should return True alse false

Comment: @palakmehta So you have a sequence of all of the elements that are common between the two arrays.  You want to know if there are any elements common between the two arrays.  The answer, therefore, is whether or not there are *any* elements in the resulting (intersect) sequence.

Comment: Seems while I was typing up my solution to the bool issue everyone else got the idea. Just check the length of the result.

Comment: @palakmehta: Servy's comment is a treasure hunt, you should concentrate on italics words and compare them with [`Enumerable` extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341635).

Comment: Yeah I actually don't have any experience with Linq I'm actually googling as I go. The Any method is a better solution.

Answer (score 10):

This will work too:

```
bool result = names.Any(subnames.Contains);
```

**EDIT**

This code may look incomplete but it actually works (method group approach).

Comment: subnames.Contains is a function which you've used no parentheses or paramaters for. You've also failed to use the LINQ Any function anywhere near correctly. Very full of bugs!

Comment: This IS valid code. It uses method group approach. Please check if it runs before commenting.

Answer (score 4):

You could use some Linq and then use `Intersect`

```
var commonNames = names.Intersect(subnames);
```

Answer (score 2):

To check if any:

```
bool anyInBoth = names.Intersect(subnames).Any();
```

To get the ones in both:

```
IEnumerable<string> inBoth = names.Intersect(subnames);
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq is the simplest I think:

```
from n1 in names
join n2 in subnames on n1 equals n2
select n1;
```

Comment: Ah, I like Gabe's answer better :)

Comment: Hey, at least you provided another option :)

Answer (score 0):

```
bool DiziIcindeDiziVarMi(string[] parent, string[] child)
{
     int say = 0;
     for (var i = 0; i < child.Length; i++)
        for (var j = 0; j < parent.Length; j++)
           if (child[i] == parent[j])
                say++;

        return say == child.Length;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way: I share both how to check one (several) word parts and all

```
string[] subnames = { "P", "G", "O" };
    
bool all = subnames.All(s => names.Contains(s));
bool anyInBoth = subnames.All(s => names.Contains(s));
```