# Check if an array sorted in ascending order is contained within another array?

Tags: c#, arrays

If I have a list,

```
int[] ints = { 4, 2, 6, 5 };
```

and I sort the list using `Array.Sort(ints)`, and I've got another array,

```
int[] i = { 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 12 };
```

how do I check that the sorted array, `ints` is contained within `i`?

If the array has extra elements,

```
int[] ints = { 4, 2, 6, 3, 5 };
```

that are not part of `i` then this should return false, unlike with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139419/how-can-we-check-whether-one-array-contains-one-or-more-elements-of-another-arra):

> Here is a Linq solution that should give you what you need:
>
> ```
> names.Any(x => subnames.Contains(x))
> ```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?  We may be table to help you fix it.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. seems like a typical [homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) to me. can you please share what you've tried and researched so far? we'll gladly help if you're stuck somewhere, but you should first attempt to solve the task on your own - and be able to describe your efforts. i recommend taking the [Tour], as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @TimSchmelter - IMHO because it should verify the sequence of the items in the array eg. if arr1 has `1, 3` and arr2 has `1, 2, 3` it should return false even though arr2 has all the elements, but it fails to contain the elements in the exact sequence

Comment: Looks like easy leetcode question. Two pointers problem. Time complexity `O(n)`  if you have sorted arrays. That's my tip for this homework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives your desired result:

```
int firstIndex = Array.IndexOf(i, ints.First());
bool sameSequenceContained = firstIndex != -1
    && i.Skip(firstIndex).Take(ints.Length).SequenceEqual(ints);
```

So first check if the first integer is contained at all, then use it's index to get the sub-sequence with `Skip` and `Take`, then use `SequenceEqual` to check if it's the same sequence.

Edit: i think it's not that easy since it's possible that there are more than one index of the first item. You could use such an extension method to find all:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> EnumerateAllIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, T item, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        if (comparer == null)
        {
            comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
        }

        int index = 0;
        foreach(T itemInSequence in sequence)
        {
            if(comparer.Equals(item, itemInSequence))
            {
                yield return index;
            }
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you are able to use this readable and efficient query:

```
bool sameSequenceContained = i.EnumerateAllIndex(ints.First())
    .Any(index => i.Skip(index).Take(ints.Length).SequenceEqual(ints));
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you can use this linq expression.

```
ints.All(num => i.Contains(num));
```

Here's the full code.

```
int[] ints = {4, 2, 6, 5};
Array.Sort(ints);

int[] i = {1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 12};

bool IsPartOf(int[] ints, int[] i)
{
    return ints.All(num => i.Contains(num));
}

Console.WriteLine(IsPartOf(ints, i));
```

Comment: Doesn’t seem to meet the requirement, if the array `i` would have the `3` it should return false IMHO because `i` than wouldn’t contain the exact elements `2, 4, 5, 6` the method should only return true if `i` contains the array `ints` in exactly it’s sequence.